# Navigation Architecture Component - BottomNavigationView avoid fragment reloading

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I am using a `BottomNavigationView` to show a bunch of fragments from my navigation graph.

The bottom nav is setup like this in my `MainActivity`:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.mainNavigationFragment)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Each fragment has its own FragmentScoped `viewmodel` to serve its content.

Cycling through each tab in the `bottomnavview`, I see the fragment being recreated which in turn causes a new instance of viewmodel to be created for that fragment. 
Which causes a fresh api calls to fetch the data again.

How can I avoid the refetching of this data ?

I am aware I can do these:

1. Use an Activity view model to host all this data, but that will just
   make a single viewmodel hosting data for all my fragments.
2. Cache the api response so the fragment recreation will just
   get data from cache, instead of making a fresh network call

Is there any platform provided best practice which I can follow to get around this refetching of data every time ?

Thank you

Comment: Hey!! Same issue here, did you get to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Hey, Can some one please provide a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this behavior (after hours of research, because overriding `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` was not an option due to some layout inconsistencies I cannot explain) with:

```
                                        | | | | |
                                        v v v v v 
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(
    item -> Log.d(MY_TAG, "navigation item " + item.getTitle() + " reselected")
);
```

or

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(item -> { } );
```

if you don't want the `Log` entry :)

Answer (score 0):

Better setup a `ViewPager` with a bottom `TabLayout` (can be styled so that it looks quite similar, except that it doesn't have those numbered badges), then you can define the off-screen threshold, which is the number of pages kept alive - while with navigation, this is quite a self-defeating approach, since the fragments just get replaced, without any if or then.